# Update event - Side case update BODY

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

The [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/%7Bid%7D) call in PATH for the body update generates an unpleasant case.

The event created as onlineMeeting with provider Teams if the body is updated, all attendees are sent the invitation as a non-online event. It will be necessary to redo the UPDATE call to re-create the event as onlineMeeting with the updated body.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

For ‘Create Event’ API, user need to explicitly pass ‘isOnlineMeeting’ field and set it to ‘true’ to ensure an online meeting is created.

For e.g. –

```
{
   ...

   "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
   "isOnlineMeeting": true,
   "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
  
    ...
}
```

Refer to example 4 of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create an event as an online meeting.

Comment: Hello, please put your code in between back ticks (`), so it looks easier to read. thanks!